# Can Linux corrupt the data on an NTFS partition?

Tags: filesystems, ntfs

I have read contradictory statements about NTFS support in Linux, for example [here](https://superuser.com/questions/32838/is-ntfs-on-ubuntu-stable) they say that NTFS is stable in Linux, while [here](https://superuser.com/questions/260752/linux-mint-10-seems-to-corrupt-ntfs-filesystem) they say that your NTFS data may get corrupted in Linux.

So can Linux corrupt the data on an NTFS partition (I am using Ubuntu, but my question is about Linux in general)?

Comment: i've had no problem with ntfs-3g 2017.3.23 from tuxera reading/writing a 3tb NTFS made from win10.  My recommendation is **disable windows fast startup** so the ntfs file system is not left in a sleep/hinbernation state.  And it's not really "corruption" more like setting the dirty flag in NTFS causing windows to do a disk check.

Comment: if linux fails to mount ntfs, don't force mount it.  Make sure windows is happy mounting and shutting down the NTFS file system in question- take microsoft windows to have the correct answer on whether an ntfs file system is clean & healthy.  Remember NTFS is a proprietary Microsoft file system.

Answer (score 4):

short answer: no.

long answer: yes, if you want to.
windows has 'hibernation'. and it is enabled by default on windows 10. it saves cache, tmp files, unfinishied task and more. this makes windows shutdown and boot process a lot faster.

writing something on this state can corrupt saved tmp files, causing windows boot with new clean session but it wont corrupt system. but writing on hibernation state can also overwrite saved unfinished task, including file movement, copy, and anything related to file. so files will be corrupted.

linux's default NTFS driver can detect hibernation, and it will mount filesystem on read-only state so you cant do anything on that filesystem unless you override that protection.
this can be fixed by turning off 'fast restart' on windows power option. this disables hibernation, allowing file editing.

additional tips:

- do not mount(RW mode) after sudden power loss. it can mess things up.
- if you want to edit just once without adjusting windows settings, type this command `shutdown /s` this will shut down systemsafely.
- be aware windows system files are not hidden or locked. those are not protected on linux and you can mess windows.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are asking a wrong question. Is it safe to access NTFS filesystem from Linux? Yes, it is. But no one can give you 100 % guarantee and your data can get corrupted. The chance is very low, but it can happen. It can happen with any filesystem (even native Linux ones). The solution is simple: backups, you can lose your data for many reasons and having a backup is the only way to be safe.

The general rules are:

- Do not hibernate Windows, always shutdown it before booting Linux. The NTFS driver can detect this and shouldn't allow mounting Windows system partition of a hibernated system.
- For removable devices, always use the "safe remove" action before disconnecting it (on both systems).

And if you are worried, mount NTFS as read-only in Linux and find a different way to share data between Windows and Linux. But there is no real reason for that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **linux will 100% corrupt your NTFS partition** sooner or later. And I'm not even talking about a sudden power loss or unexpected device removal. Those will definitely mess up NTFS on linux.
I'm talking about a normal use. Here's an example:

1. Checkout a big project (like, Unreal Engine source code).
2. Run the initial setup and build commands.
3. Hit Ctrl+C at some point.
4. Done! In case you've been using an HDD, your file system is busted. For an SSD drive, there's a 50% probability your FS is done for.
5. Try to reboot your PC. You will see it will never turn off, cause some disk-related daemon just prevents it from shutting down. It might take few hours to actually reboot. Otherwise, you can just force reboot it. Waiting won't change a thing, though.
6. After you turn on your PC, you'll notice a 100% disk usage. NTFS will be mounted in read-only mode. You won't be able to remount it, copy files or perform any actions. Depending on a distro, having a non-responsive drive in your system may also freeze the GUI.
7. There's no way to repair the drive from linux. None of the GUI or command line utilities worked for me, no matter how hard I tried. Most of them won't even display the list of drives, they'll just hang forever.
8. How do you repair it? By using Windows. Your system will take like half an hour to boot to Windows, but when it's finally done, you can try right clicking the drive and selecting some repair options.
9. You'll have to reboot and wait for a few hours until Windows repairs your drive.
10. After that, you can boot back into linux, and the drive will be mounted in R/W mode. Of course, some files will be lost.

This is the way to break your NTFS in just a few clicks. But what if you don't work with git and don't copy lots of files? Are you safe? The answer is a big fat **no**. Linux will break your NTFS drive, it's just a matter of time. It may take a week or a month for enough of broken files to accumulate. And you might loose some important data in case you notice it too late.

We can only wonder, why was NTFS support not implemented in last 30 years. Anyway, at this point I suppose it will never be added.
So, there you have it. One more reason to keep you from installing a linux distro on your device. At the very least, make sure you don't mount your windows boot drive, or a disk with any important info.

Comment: Which filesystem driver are (were) you using? Name and version would be really helpful here.

Comment: It doesn't matter. The issue is still there- all the way from Ubuntu 12 to Ubuntu 22 (and later). Same applies to other distros.

Comment: Of course it matters. There are two NTFS drivers that I know of, but as I don't run Ubuntu I know neither which one nor its version number

Comment: No, it doesn't. There's no way to get it to work properly. No matter what drivers, versions, distros, whatever you install.

Comment: It's not possible to test and submit a bug report without the necessary details

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Hirasawa-yui Hirasawa Yui's reported experience, I am experiencing a very rare but repeating corruption of NTFS on different drives with different use cases. But it may be limited to certain kernel versions and certain ntfs-3g versions. Haven't isolated the problem yet, however the way the symptoms show up is that an instance of VMWARE using a vmdk file residing on NTFS will start throwing a lot of errors in the journal. I'm copying it here in case someone finds it helpful.

dbus-daemon[1849]: [system] Rejected: destination has a full message queue, 0 matched rules; type="error", sender="(unset)" ((bus)) interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown" requested_reply="1" destination=":1.189" (uid=1000 pid=30716 comm="/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-vmx -ssnapshot.numRolli" label="unconfined")

When I boot to Windows and chkdsk that partition, in the windows console chkdsk shows the filesystem is ok... HOWEVER in the event log it shows the filesystem has problems.
The ONLY way to correct this condition is to copy the entire filesystem on another location, delete and recrate the partition and copy data back.

Having said all the above, all software can have bugs and for the most part ntfs-3g package in Linux is mostly working really well for over 4-5 years of usage and I have often moved 3-4 TB of data around without problems.

Comment: Which filesystem driver are you using? Name and version would be really helpful here.

Comment: @roaima Is this the name/version you're asking about? Thanks
`$ apt policy ntfs-3g
ntfs-3g:
  Installed: 1:2017.3.23-2ubuntu0.18.04.2
  Candidate: 1:2017.3.23-2ubuntu0.18.04.3
  Version table:
     1:2017.3.23-2ubuntu0.18.04.3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1:2017.3.23-2ubuntu0.18.04.2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:2017.3.23-2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages`